Trouble executing Python executable within an Electron-React application on macOS despite successful execution on Windows
I'm facing an unexpected challenge while trying to execute a Python executable within an Electron-React application on macOS, utilizing spawn() method. The following code snippet executes smoothly on Windows, but on macOS, it fails to initiate without any accompanying error messages:
ipcMain.on('open-python', (event, params) => {
  try {
    log.info('Log from the main process for the python app ');
    const amePath = pythonExecutablePath;
    log.info('AMEPATH: ', amePath);
    const ameProcess = spawn(amePath, params, {
      detached: true,
      stdio: 'ignore',
      shell: true,
      encoding: 'utf8',
    });

    ameProcess.unref();
    log.info('ameprocess completed successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    log.error('Error occurred while spawning Python process:', error);
  }
});

Despite ensuring that all paths and parameters are correct, the process doesn't seem to initiate on macOS. I've ensured that there are no error messages, but the process simply doesn't start.
Could someone shed some light on why this might be happening? Are there any platform-specific considerations I'm overlooking that could explain this behavior? Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.
I've also tried utilizing the execFile function, but encountered similar issues.

what does that log.info with amePath actually prints ?
